# jQuery map breaking up a plain string and adding <br> when not needed

Tags: jquery

I am using the following:

```
var items = $.map(json.errors, function (error) {
return error + '</br>';
}).join('');
```

json.errors can be `IEnumerable<string>` or just string.

When json.errors is IEnumerable then items is populated with text with a `<br>` between each error message. However when json.errors is a string then items is populated with the error string with a `<br>` after every character of the string.

Is there some way that I could fix the problem for when json.errors is just a plain string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your current code adds a `<br/>` after every string, and not just *between* strings, this would be equivalent:

```
if (typeof json.errors === "string" ) {
    json.errors = [ json.errors ] ;
}

// continue as before
```

Answer (score 2):

Test `json.errors`'s type first, and only proceed to modify its contents if it's not a string. You can get the type by using `typeof`:

```
if ( typeof json.errors === "string" ) {
  // Proceed understanding you're handling a string
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is way over my head :-)  How can I test the type? Would another solution to this be placing the string